# If $f\colon X\to Y$ is nullhomotopic, then $I_2(f,Z)=0$ for closed $Z\subset Y$ of complementary dimension?

Tags: differential-topology, intersection-theory

I think I have a near solution, but one doubt. Problem 2.4.4 on page 83 of Guillemin and Pollack asks

> If $f\colon X\to Y$ is homotopic to a constant map, show that $I_2(f,Z)=0$ for all complementary dimensional closed $Z$ in $Y$, except parhaps if $\dim X=0$.

Assume $\dim X\geq 1$, so $\dim Z<\dim Y$. Suppose $f\sim c_{y_0}$, where $c_{y_0}$ is the constant map with image $\{y_0\}$. If $y_0\notin Z$, the claim is clear. So suppose $y_0\in Z$. Since $Z$ is a proper subset of $Y$, there exists $y\notin Z$. If $\gamma\colon I\to Y$ is a smooth path from $y_0$ to $y$, then the map $F\colon X\times I\to Y$ defined by $F(x,t)=\gamma(t)$ is a homotopy from $c_{y_0}$ to $c_y$. So I see that $f\sim c_y$. Since the mod $2$ intersection number is homotopy invariant, it follows that 
$$
I_2(f,Z)=I_2(c_y,Z)=0
$$
since $c_y^{-1}(Z)=\emptyset$.

The thing bothering me is, how can I be sure there exists at least one $y\notin Z$ that is path connected to $y_0$?

Comment: Composite the homotopy between $f$ and the constant map $c_y$.

Comment: @jimbo I don't see how that addresses my question that a path from $y_0$ to some $y\notin Z$ exists.

Comment: happens $y\notin{Z}$ because the $\dim Z<\dim Y$.

Comment: @jimbo I know there exist $y\notin Z$, but why should there necessarily be a path connecting one of these points to $y_0$?

Comment: Take a neighborhood diffeomorphic to an $n$-ball around $y$ and choose a point not in $Z$ in there.

Comment: @aes How do you know there are coordinate charts around $y$ which aren't entirely contained in $Z$? Are closed measure $0$ sets nowhere dense? That would imply $Z$ is nowhere dense, so then all coordinate charts would not be entirely contained in $Z$ even...

Comment: @KaitlynSchweed The image of the chart is an $n$-manifold, and it intersected with $Z$ is a submanifold of lower dimension. How to find a point not in the submanifold? Method 1: Sard's theorem. Method 2 (more elementary but not as short to say): Use the local form of an immersion plus the fact that it's a submanifold and thus has the subspace topology to get a chart in which the preimage of the submanifold is a proper linear subspace in an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.